# Syntax Error Creating a table with a column named 'desc'

Tags: mysql

I can never seem to be able to create MySQL tables with columns of the type TEXT. Here's my MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE factions(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), name VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, desc TEXT NOT NULL, admins TEXT NOT NULL, mods TEXT, members TEXT, land TEXT, enemies TEXT, allies TEXT)
```

When it's run, I get this:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc text NOT NULL, admins text NOT NULL, mods text, members text, land text, en' at line 1
```

I can't figure out what's wrong! I'm using Java if it makes any difference.

Comment: On another note, I am pretty sure your use of TEXT for most of these columns is incorrect

Comment: Yeah, most of those TEXT uses were pretty bad. Fortunately, I have improved a great deal since I originally asked this question.

Comment: I figured you probably had ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`desc` is a reserved word and **shouldn't** be used as a name of a column. You **can** use `desc` as a name of a column, but if you do, you must always wrap it in back-ticks.

```
CREATE TABLE factions(
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY(id), 
   name    VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, 
   `desc`  TEXT NOT NULL, 
   admins  TEXT NOT NULL, 
   mods    TEXT, 
   members TEXT, 
   land    TEXT, 
   enemies TEXT, 
   allies  TEXT
);
```

The above is tested and works, but since you'll always have to wrap it in back-ticks (in every `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`) you may want to change the name, or just get in the habit of wrapping all fields in back-ticks, which has other advantages.

Answer (score 1):

change the column name `desc` to any something different since it is a reserverd word for `descend` or `describe`

Answer (score 0):

`desc` is a reserved word and <strike>can't</strike> *shall not* be given as a name to a table or column. You may use `description` as the column name. With the name change, your statement should work.